# Doctrine / Symfony: Yamldriver and SimpleYamlDriver compatibility in external library

Tags: doctrine-orm, yaml, external, symfony, vendor

I'm working on the creation of an external library that contains database information, such as entities, repositories and so on.

The purpose is to use this library in symfony projects, but also in another project that support doctrine2.

We encountered a problem in Yml files that contains entities configuration. 
We named it with dot to separate file path, and with the extension .dcm.yml as it was specified in doctrine documentation, it works fine in projects, but not in sf3 project...

I search in configuration, and everywhere, but i found nothing to just specify to symfony which driver he had to use to parse config file...

I found that there are two drivers, one is the native Yaml driver, and another one powered by symfony named simpleYamlDriver.

I think there is a solution to this problem, but I don't found it. Can you help us ?